# AJAX loaded content not initialising (prettyPhoto)

Tags: html, ajax, dom

I am using AJAX to load content of which works perfectly when it loads with the DOM but during AJAX load it fails to initialise.

I am not exactly sure how to proceed to fix this.

[Example (the basic loaded DOM)](http://ariia.co.uk/portfolio/examples/6/index-2.html#portfolio)

When you click an image it opens into a modal like preview. But when i load the same content via AJAX, when the pictures are clicked it just treats as a hyperlink and goes to the reference instead of opening into the preview player as expected.

I am 99% sure this is due to the element being loaded into the DOM after initialisation.

**An example of a snippet of code that should be loading when clicked a preview**

```
<div class="img-thumb">
    <a vdh-685872771="" data-pp="prettyPhoto[blog-gallery]" href="//xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu/home/scripts/<? echo $licensePath; ?>" title="Fashion and Style for the Future">
    <div class="img-thumb-hover">
        <i class="im-expand2"></i></div>
    </a>
    <img alt="blog-image" class="img-responsive" src="//xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu/home/scripts/<? echo $licensePath; ?>">
</div>
```

Comment: you are right! Have a look at event-delegation and mainly at the .on() function. You need it to run jQuery on elements that are not in the DOM when the page load

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a solution to my problem. The issue is DOM related as @Lelio Faieta stated. However after much reading i returned to the original documentation for prettyPhoto the specific script that seems to be the issue here.

There i found this very nice solution with prettyPhoto and Ajax.

To return content via AJAX and have it initialise you can do the following with the `rel` attribute of your `a`

```
rel="prettyPhoto[ajax]"
```

By stating `ajax` in the brackets of prettyPhoto, this allows to add the content into the DOM with very little effort.

Example of the full `a` to be loaded via `AJAX`.

```
<a rel="prettyPhoto[ajax]" href="//xxxxxxx.eu/home/scripts/<? echo $licensePath; ?>">Ajax content</a>
```

This works without any need to add any new functions or edit any existing functions.

[PrettyPhoto Documentation](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/)